# add class to a link having a specific href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a class if `href` attribute is equal to a variable value.

In this example the first element should have gold background;

```js
let a = 'a_xp_notes.php';
$('.lmlink[href = ${a}]').addClass('.act');
```

```css
.lmlink{display:block;}
.act{background:gold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='lmlink' href='a_xp_notes.php'>NOTES</a>
<a class='lmlink' href='a_xp_persons.php'>PERSONS</a>
<a class='lmlink' href='a_xp_comps.php'>COMPS</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the dot(`.`) in `addClass('.act')`

Second try with the following example

```js
let a = 'a_xp_notes.php';
$(`.lmlink[href='${a}']`).addClass('act');
```

```css
.lmlink{display:block;}
.act{background:gold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='lmlink' href='a_xp_notes.php'>NOTES</a>
<a class='lmlink' href='a_xp_persons.php'>PERSONS</a>
<a class='lmlink' href='a_xp_comps.php'>COMPS</a>
```

Comment: @qadenza No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jquery in this case unless there is a logical evaluation. You can do the same using only css and it's `href` selector

```css
.lmlink {
  display: block;
}

a[href="a_xp_notes.php"] {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='lmlink' href='a_xp_notes.php'>NOTES</a>
<a class='lmlink' href='a_xp_persons.php'>PERSONS</a>
<a class='lmlink' href='a_xp_comps.php'>COMPS</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

User Javascript [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)   (back-ticks instead of single quotes)

```
$(`.lmlink[href = ${a}]`).addClass('act');
```